# Corrupt NTFS folders java

Tags: java, directory, ntfs, corrupt

I have more than 80 thousand folders. Each of these folder contains 4 sub-folders an 1 file. I need to list all or some of these 80 thousand folders to get the sub-folders and then list sub-folders to get the list of files inside sub-folders. For this I developed a Java program which works fine on most of these folders. On some specific folders the program freezes. After killing the program, When I double-click these folders to open them a message pops up saying the folder is corrupt and no longer accessible. These folders are on an NTFS volume for which CHKDSK in read-only mode reports errors. Is there any way I can know in in advance that a specific folder is corrupt and ignore processing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can run CHKDSK from Java, read it's output and skip those files/directories. This would slow down your application but might be better than stopping on a bad sector etc.  Or you could upgrade your OS to one which doesn't do this. ;)

You are better off fixing your filesystem. Java assumes your sub-systems work as that is their job.

Comment: But chkdsk works only for volumes. The filename switch in CHKDSK works only for file frgamentation information. And also the file system is on the hard disk of some other person. I don't want to make any changes to his file system and I don't care whether this he can access this data or not.

Comment: @ShailPandey He doesn't appear to either.  You would need to do a CHKDSK for the whole drive in any case, you can't scan just one folder.